# Connection fails in SSH tunneling

Tags: ssh-tunnel

I have a web server running on port 8000 on remotehost. I set up a tunnel from localhost:

```
    ssh -L 8888:localhost:8000 remotehost
```

However when I try to request localhost:8888 I get:

```
    channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
```

on the terminal. Why does the connection fail? How should I fix it?

Comment: On remotehost, what happens if you do "telnet 127.0.0.1 8000"?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like there's nothing on that port on the other side at localhost:8000. Use `netstat` to verify that something is listening.

Answer (score 0):

In your sshd_config file on the remotehost do you have this?

```
AllowTcpForwarding yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting to localhost:8000 on `remotehost`. It could be that there is no program running on that port.